# Responsive divs stacked on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I'd like to set up a webpage as the below image shows:

- The pink box and white box should stay within the center 1350px
- The distance between pink and whiet box can be variable as long as it stays within center 1350px
- The yellow and blue boxes need grow and shrink both vertically and horizontally to fill the entire space (1:2 ratio) as the user resizes the window
- The pink box must overlap the yellow and blue boundary with ~10-20% of the pink box within the blue
- White and pink should never overlap and should maintain some minimum distance between them while resolution > 992px

[image: Image of the layout I'd like]

**Things I've Tried** (that almost worked)

- Using the grid layout, I am able to get the pink and white items spaced apart correctly within the 1350px center. However, the yellow and blue boxes also do not exceed the 1350px boundary. (Since I'm setting max-width)
- Using flexbox, I've gotten it to a point where yellow and blue stretch horizontally/vertically. However, I don't know how to confine the pink and white boxes to be within the center 1350px. Is there a way to do this?

> // I'd like to add in max-width: 1350px somewhere

**Markup and style**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: gold;
  max-width: 33%;
  padding-top: 70px;
  
  flex-basis: 33%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.blue {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 66%;
  padding-top: 70px;
  
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 2;
}
.white {
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 20%;
/*   left: 0px; */
}
.pink {
/*   background-color: hotpink; */
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: -350px;
/*   right: 0px; */
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="boundary">
<div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="white"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="yellow">
    <div class="pink">
      <img src="https://cdn.psychologytoday.com/sites/default/files/styles/article-inline-half-caption/public/field_blog_entry_images/2018-09/cooldownpink.jpg?itok=-SDuFsdT" />
    </div>
  </div>    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/icswim14/pen/gOgrzyB)

**Additional context:**

- pink is an image with fixed ratio and fixed height (650px)
- white is an HTML element
- yellow and blue are only used to color the background

**Can this be done? What is the best way to do this responsively?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSS grid solution. I used pseudo element for the yellow and blue since they are only used for the background coloration:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max((100vw - 1350px)/2, 0px) repeat(8, 1fr) max((100vw - 1350px)/2, 0px);
}

body > *,
body::before,
body::after{
  grid-row: 1;
}

body::before {
  content:"";
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 1/span 4;
}

body::after {
  content:"";
  background: blue;
  grid-column: span 6/-1;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 3/span 3;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index:1;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  grid-column: 7/span 2;
  height: 40%;
  margin: auto 0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
```